# Find max value from grouped list of clusters of similar numbers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I'm working on k-mean algorthim to cluster list of number, If i have an array (X)

```
 X=array([[0.85142858],[0.85566274],[0.85364912],[0.81536489],[0.84929932],[0.85042336],[0.84899714],[0.82019115], [0.86112067],[0.8312496 ]])
```

then I run the following code

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=5, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
cluster.fit_predict(X)

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("%4d " % cluster.labels_[i], end=""); print(X[i])
```

i got the results

```
1 [0.85142858]
   3 [0.85566274]
   3 [0.85364912]
   0 [0.81536489]
   1 [0.84929932]
   1 [0.85042336]
   1 [0.84899714]
   0 [0.82019115]
   4 [0.86112067]
   2 [0.8312496]
```

how to get the max number in each cluster ? like this

```
0: 0.82019115
1: 0.85142858
2: 0.8312496
3: 0.85566274
4: 0.86112067
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(cluster.labels_,X)).groupby(0).max().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'id',1:'max_val'})
```

result:

```
   id   max_val
0   0  0.820191
1   1  0.851429
2   2  0.831250
3   3  0.855663
4   4  0.861121
```

Answer (score 0):

what about if i want to display value of (i), the result looks like

```
0: 0.82019115   8
1: 0.85142858   1
2: 0.8312496    10
3: 0.85566274   2
4: 0.86112067   9
```